# Executing .jar file from PHP through cmd prompt and capturing output

Tags: java, php, popen

I have a jar file of my application which has more than one class. The jar file is called by PHP through the command prompt. I am using the following PHP snippet to call the jar file.

```
<?php
$result=popen('java -jar D:\\Development\\Filehandler\\dist\\Filehandler.jar getConfigLang', "r");
while(!feof($result)){
  print fread($result, 1024);
  flush();
}
fclose($result);
?>
```

The problem here is interesting. I am able to get the 'System.out.println' statements which are in the main function. But unable to get the output statements from other classes.

I have tried with exec() also. The .jar is working fine and when called from the command prompt directly, its working fine.

Is there a way to capture the whole output?

Comment: Did you try running without PHP first?

Comment: Yeah, its working fine when tried directly in command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using proc_open instead:

`http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php`

it allows you to setup the pipes "Will be set to an indexed array of file pointers that correspond to PHP's end of any pipes that are created."

Example from php.net

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
```